# I want text to not re-size or move css

Tags: html, css

I want to make it so that when a use CTRL + or -, the text is not affected like the image below it. I've tried webkit, using percent instead op pixel vaues, but it doesn't work.

```css
.header {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        height: 7%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #424242;
    }
    
    .body {
        margin: 0;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 0;
    }
    
    .main {
    }
    
    .hub {
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-right: 10%;
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: coolvetica;
        src: url("font/coolvetica rg.ttf");
    }
    
    .title {
        font-family: coolvetica;
        font-size: x-large;
        line-height: 180%;
        margin-top: 0.35%;
        margin-bottom: 0.35%;
        height: 80%;
        left: 1%;
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .navbar {
        position: fixed;
        top: 2%;
        left: 14%;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    .item {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
    }
    
    .label {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 8px;
    }
    
    .title-box {
        height: 100%;
        line-height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TheShieldNetwork</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body class="body">
        <div class="header">
            <p class="title">TheShieldNetwork</p>
            <ul class="navbar">
                <li class="item"><a class="label" href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
                <li class="item"><a class="label" href="news.asp">News</a></li>
                <li class="item"><a class="label" href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="item"><a class="label" href="about.asp">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <img class="hub" width="80%" height="80%" src="img/background.png" alt="Hub">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can see the website at www.theshieldnetwork.com. Do you have any idea how I would be able to fix it.

Comment: that's an image, i belive that trick will only work with images.

Comment: Is there any way to make text behave like an image? @Gusman

Comment: you can use media query to vary the size while zoom in/out. But we can't bring like image.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl- OR + are the browser way to zoom in/out, 
it's especially for helping people out.. (elderly people, and so..) .

Chrome (webkit) supported it until version:28.0.1500.11

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%
```

But this is only supported now by iOS as far as I can tell, so Chrome will simply ignore it and continue to use something called [font boosting](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=FontBoosting)

There is a solution, even if it’s a messy one. Setting a max-height greater then the elements height on one of the parents elements seems to resolve this issue. For instance:

```
<div class="outer">
    <ul>    
        <li>This is a simple list</li>
        <li>With list items that get scaled</li>
        <li>How annoying!</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
.outer {
        max-height: 5000em;
    }
```

This seems to resolve the issue. Even though it’s not ideal.

Or you can always replace all your text with images - not ideal either.